# Useful AutoIt scripts?

Tags: windows, automation, autoit

AutoHotkey's functionality is really great, but the more I get into it, the more I hate the syntax.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294285/python-for-autohotkey-style-key-combination-sniffing-automation/294461#294461) makes me want to try AutoIt instead:

> You may want to look at AutoIt. It does everything that AutoHotKey can do, but the language syntax doesn't make you want to pull your hair out.

But a cursory search doesn't find lists of killer apps like it does for AHK.  ([1](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/) [2](http://lifehacker.com/5598693/the-best-time+saving-autohotkey-tricks-you-should-be-using) [3](http://tech.blorge.com/Structure:%20/2008/02/04/10-autohotkey-scripts-to-wildly-boost-productivity-windows-xp/) vs [1](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/123506-general-windows-autocorrect/) [2](http://dailycupoftech.com/useful-autoit-scriptlets/))  It seems mostly used for automating games or something?

So, to copy [Useful AutoHotkey scripts?](https://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts), what are you favorite, most used, AutoIt scripts?

Comment: "Useful AutoHotkey scripts?" gets 42 votes, but "Useful AutoIt scripts?" is off-topic.  :D

Comment: Like any scripting language, everyone one has their own personal library of a few to hundreds of scripts/apps that they keep and use regularly for a large variety of tasks. This questions would be better served by focusing on a specific task. I could post 100 examples of useful scripts, but they may not be useful to 99% of those who read this, which makes asking pointless to the purpose of this site. What do you want to do with AutoIt? You should really start by reading the AutoIt documentation for script examples and function explanations: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/

Comment: @MaQleod: We should be able to ask questions like this and vote up each others' answers when they're good or helpful, so that the best examples get the most votes and rise in visibility